# threejs - GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Invalid operation on multisampled framebuffer

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to combine post-processing with "THREE.WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget" but it gives me the following error in the console
`[WebGL-000052BE06CD9380] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Invalid operation on multisampled framebuffer`

when using the regular "THREE.WebGLRenderTarget" there is no error. couldn't found a solution for this problem. is someone familiar with this?

Here is the code:

```
// Render target
let RenderTargerClass = null


if (renderer.getPixelRatio() === 1 && renderer.capabilities.isWebGL2){
    RenderTargerClass = THREE.WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget
    console.log("using WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget")
} else {
    RenderTargerClass = THREE.WebGLRenderTarget
    console.log("using WebGLRenderTarget")
}

const renderTarget = new RenderTargerClass(
    800,
    600,
    {
        minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
        encoding: THREE.sRGBEncoding
    }
)

// Composer
const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget)
```

Comment: Maybe your encoding is the problem? I know Linear encoding is the default, and sRGB is only valid for a material's map. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Textures

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding property is the problem. In [THREE.WebGLRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) a [THREE.Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Texture#api/en/textures/Texture) is created and the encoding property is passed. If you look at the documentation of [THREE.Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Texture#api/en/textures/Texture) the THREE.sRGBEncoding option is not valid. Use one of the options listed there.
Note: THREE.WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget is deprecated, you can replace RenderTargerClass with [THREE.WebGLRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32197836)